# How to deal with a manager that can not keep up his promises

Tags: management

A manager has done the following:

- He promised his team member of an oversea deployment opportunity but later changed his mind and simply gave this chance to someone else without a good reason. All he said was: "xxx will get this job."
- Every week, he came to team meeting without any preparation at all; he would apologize first by saying: "I am sorry I am not prepared enough for this meeting" and happily chit-chat for the rest of the meeting. Next week, he would do this again.
- He kept talking about getting tasks from other teams and assign those tasks to his team members, but next day, he simply forgot.
- During one power-point presentation by his team member, he played with cell phone throughout the presentation AND gave his opinions in the end.
- Lied a few times into his team members' face.

Is there anything we can do to change his mindset? Has anyone dealt with people like before?

Comment: "Has anyone dealt with people like before?" - yes, and the only solution is to freshen up your resume and go somewhere else - it is almost impossible to change the behaviour of someone you work under

Comment: Are you afraid that he'll fire you? If he's not prepared, get up and leave the room. Tell him that he's wasting your time. For the powerpoint presentation, his team member should have just cut his presentation short. That being said, the powerpoint presentation of that team member could have been boring and awful. In which case, that team member needs to be given some strict guidelines on how do presentations correctly and present them in a fraction of the time. It may even be necessary to forbid him from using Powerpoint (or Powerpoint equivalent) for his next presentation.

Comment: Some of the worst bosses I had turned out to be best for my career. Because they didn't step up and do their jobs, I did and that got me promoted. Others made me step out of my comfort zone and look for a better job and, lo and behold, I found one. One that I never would have been looking for if I hadn't had a bad boss. A bad boss can be a gift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all else fails, tell HIS boss what's going on, and how YOU can do a better job.  If you're not prepared to do a better job, then you might want to let your boss BE the boss.  He's not obligated to you.

No, it's not a nice situation.  But that's why people get new jobs.